# VS Code cannot select older python kernel for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have python 3.7 and 3.9 installed on my system.

In VS Code I am starting a new python Jupyter notebook. VS Code asks to select a Python interpreter, but shows only a couple different versions of 3.9
(As an aside, I do not know why 3.9 is installed both in /usr/bin and in /usr/local/bin).
I cannot select python 3.7 from this list that automatically shows up.

If I press command+P to open the VS Code command pallete, and then type "select python interpreter", I *CAN* select python 3.7, but it has no effect. VS Code remains using 3.9.

I can select the 3.7 interpreter for regular old `...py` python files and run them with 3.7.

But how can I select python 3.7 for a Jupyter notebook in vs code?

[image]

Comment: Is your 3.7 interpreter in the `PATH`?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall python3.7?

Comment: Python 3.7 works. I can choose it for regular python files. If I create `test.py` and run it with `python3 test.py` in the terminal, the version will report 3.7. But for a jupyter notebook suddenly I can only choose the latest 3.9 version as a notebook interpreter.

Comment: If you are using anaconda, does the version not change when you download a new version from there and select that env and start it?

Comment: I don't use anaconda, I just switch python interpreters in VS Code.